# Switching workspace using mouse wheel under dock panel is no longer working

Tags: workspaces, mouse-scroll, workspace-switcher, mouse-wheel

Switching between workspaces using the mouse wheel under the dock is no longer working (Note: Panel mode is off). It was working until a few days and suddenly stopped working in v22.04, Also tried to upgrade the version to 23.04 but it remains the same.

Does anyone have this experience and found any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using this extension as an alternative option. This extension enables the same behaviour but we can use the mouse scroll on the top panel.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/701/top-panel-workspace-scroll/